# Dictionary data structure that uses entry's field as a key

Tags: oop, data-structures, dictionary, d

Data records of some kind frequently have to be indexed by a unique key. Usually it looks something like this (I'm using C# because it's the language I'm most comfortable with, but this question isn't specific to it):

```
public class NamedRecord
{
    public readonly string UniqueImmutableName;
    ...
}

public class UsesUsualDict
{

    Dictionary<string, NamedRecord> myDict = new Dictionary<string, NamedRecord>();

    void AddRecord(NamedRecord _NewRecord)
    {
        myDict[_NewRecord.UniqueImmutableName] = _NewRecord;
    }

    NamedRecord GetRecord(string _Key)
    {
        return myDict[_Key];
    }

}
```

However, this seems a little redundant: keys in that dictionary should always be considered equal to `NamedRecord.UniqueImmutableName`, but developer ends maintaining this relationship himself. Also, this kind of data duplication just doesn't feel right to me.

Sometimes I see a solution that is similar: data record doesn't even have the UniqueImmutableName as their member. For example, in his [tutorial for D language](http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=1381876&seqNum=5), Andrei Alexandrescu uses data struct that depicts word statistics of character in a play:

```
struct PersonaData {
   uint totalWordsSpoken;
   uint[string] wordCount;
}
```

But the character's name isn't even in it — it's only available as a key to the dictionary these structs are saved in. Outside of that context, this data structure is almost useless.

What I want to do is something like that:

```
public class UsesLambdaDict
{
    LambdaDictionary<string, NamedRecord> myDict = new LambdaDictionary<string, NamedRecord>(NamedRecord _Record => _Record.UniqueImmutableName);

    void AddRecord(NamedRecord _NewRecord)
    {
        myDict.Add(_NewRecord);
    }

    NamedRecord GetRecord(string _Key)
    {
        return myDict[_Key];
    }
}
```

It seems to me that this way of handling such data records is better, because the relationship between the NamedRecord's UniqueImmutableName member and the dictionary it's saved in is formalized at compile-time. The downside I see is that there's no way to ensure that given lambda will is a pure function, at least in C#. I don't really know D so well, but it seems that `pure` keyword it has can't it guarantee neither.

So, I have several questions about this:

1. Is this even a real problem to being with? The downsides to the first solution that I have are somewhat theoretical — may be there's nothing wrong about it after all.
2. What are other possible ways to solve it?
3. What are other possible downsides to the proposed solution?

Comment: > C# ... but this question isn't specific to it

Comment: To which language this question specific?

Comment: It's not specific to any languages, but since I use C# and mention D, I decided to tag them.

Answer (score 1):

1.) I do not think so.

2.) Use structure with key and value, I do not think lambdas are necessary

3.) Performance issues (cache misses)

Answer (score 1):

1 - The overhead is not nearly high enough where it is worth worrying about.  Since the string is a reference type and immutable, you are not storing two strings, just an additional reference to the same string (or any other key).

Granted, you could write the dictionary so that you do not separately store the key and value, but only the value (and then look up the key in this object).  However, at most you are saving (PtrSize (4 or 8 bytes) * size of backing array)), which should usually be pretty small.  Plus, you may get an indirection when you go to the stored object to find where to look up the key value (which might be elsewhere in memory), resulting in a cache miss.

If you wanted to roll your own dictionary to do this though, check out this free ebook:

http://www.syncfusion.com/resources/techportal/ebooks/datastructurespart2

They go through how to hash this, so it should be pretty easy.  Alternatively, you can just copy from the mono project source code.

Comment: Oh, I'm not worried about the memory footprint. I only worry about data duplication because of logical implications, not because it takes additional space.

Comment: If the value is immutable, you have nothing to worry about (it never changes so keeping a copy doesn't matter), if the value is mutable, then you have a bigger problem.  If the value changes, the hashcode will change, and then it will be in the wrong bin/not-looked-up correctly).  You would have to wire the dictionary to reposition itself on every update to the value, this is really something to avoid.